# npm install resulting in 'ENOENT: no such file or directory'

Tags: node.js, npm

I've installed Node.js for Windows and I'm trying to install a package via npm. The command prompt is in the directory of the project (C:\Users\username\Desktop\NodeTest), which contains a single helloworld.js file. Upon typing 'npm install express', I receive the following error:

`ENOENT: no such file or direcotry, open 'C:\Users\username\package.json`

I'm attempting this from a clean install and cmd is running as admin.

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you have `package.json` in your project??

Answer (score 26, accepted):

As already pointed out by Subburaj this is because you are missing a `package.json`.
Just run `npm init` to initialize that file for you; afterwards it should work.

Comment: Great, thanks. Both tutorials I was following failed to include this step.

Comment: Or you're in a different directory from the one you have the *package.json* in.

Answer (score 48):

I was facing the same issue. I firstly delete my `node_modules` and delete the cache by following command:

```
rm -rf node_modules && npm cache clean --force
```

then I delete the `package-lock.json` file from my project and then hit `npm install` in command prompt and it works.

Comment: deleting package-lock.json is the key.  Thanks

Answer (score 10):

If you are working on a Windows machine using Vagrant/VM, there's a chance that symlinks are the culprit for your problem. To determine if that is the case, simply copy your `package.json` and `package-lock.json` into a test directory that is not mounted/shared between OSs.

```
mkdir /tmp/symlinktest
cd {{your directory with your package*.json}}
cp package*.json /tmp/symlinktest
cd /tmp/symlinktest
npm install
```

If this results in a successful install, you'll need to either exclude the `node_modules` directory from the mount (there's various articles on doing this, however I can't say I've had success) or run `npm install` outside the mounted volume.

Comment: A perfect example of how SO answers can help even when the question doesn't include the edge case (vagrant). Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

I deleted the package-lock.json and It worked for me.

Answer (score 3):

Basically I was Offline while I tried to install with npm, so go online and try 
`npm install` again

Answer (score 0):

Check the project folder which you opened in microsoft visual code. Generally you are not in the right path so npm is not able to search the package.json ... My project was in Document/hostel/hostel .. I opened Document/hostel ... So npm tried to find the package.json in Documents folder .. When i entered one level inside to Document/hostel/hostel .. it was fixed.

Answer (score 0):

i fixed it by cd into the folder in the terminal

Answer (score 0):

Delete you package-lock.json and then run the command `npm i`.

You can then create back the package-lock.json with the command.

```
npm i --package-lock-only
```

Answer (score 0):

you have first enter `npm init` command then use command

```
npm install -g npm@10.0.0
```

then use `npx`

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem like this.

I simply went to the node installation file and copied that npm file from the below path.
*C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm*

And as the terminal/command prompt shows: no such file or directory
C:\Users\YourSystemName\AppData\Roaming\npm. I paste that I have copied from the installation file as per the above mentioned in the path C:\Users\YourSystemName\AppData\Roaming\copiedfile(npm)).

After that, it's working properly for me.