# When I m trying to execute My React code constantly keep getting error - "eonent that no such file, repository"

Tags: reactjs

This is an error after put execution command - "npm start"

npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall open
npm ERR! path C:\Users\bharat sharma\my-app/package.json
npm ERR! errno -4058
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\bharat sharma\my-app\package.json'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\bharat sharma\AppData\Local\npm-cache_logs\2021-07-10T18_28_33_764Z-debug.log

Comment: This error comes arises because some dependencies are missing. Some of those might not be in the .json file mentioned in the error message. Install all necessary dependencies and it should work out fine

Comment: Does this answer help you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38143558/npm-install-resulting-in-enoent-no-such-file-or-directory ? Projects that use `node` and `npm` typically need to have a "package.json" file in order to work properly - you can run `npm init` to create this `package.json` file. If you already had a proper `package.json`, try deleting `package-lock.json` and the `node_modules` folder, and run `npm install` again