# Reactjs - npm start not opening in browser

Tags: reactjs, npm

I am following [this tutorial](https://reactjs.org/tutorial/tutorial.html#setup-option-2-local-development-environment) to learn React. All is going smoothly until I run 'npm start', then I recieve this error message:

npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall open
npm ERR! path C:\Users\hwrobo\OneDrive\Desktop\Coursework\Week 13\reactTutorial/package.json
npm ERR! errno -4058
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\hwrobo\OneDrive\Desktop\Coursework\Week 13\reactTutorial\package.json'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\npm-cache_logs\2021-09-08T13_49_13_202Z-debug.log

I'm not entirely sure what it means. Is it not able to find my folder?

Comment: Make sure you are in the correct path in the console. Where are you typing npm start?

Comment: The error is self explanatory. Make sure you have package,json file in the application root folder.

Comment: Your first path has a single `/` while most of the path is made of `\ `, which seems particularly odd.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question may be helpful. [npm install resulting in 'ENOENT: no such file or directory'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38143558/npm-install-resulting-in-enoent-no-such-file-or-directory)

Seems like your problem could reside where you are running your `npm install` . You want to make sure your running the command in the same directory as the `package.json` file. Which is usually at the root of the project.