# NextJs app initialization fail - ENOENT npm error

Tags: next.js

I'm trying to initialize a Nextjs App using: npx create-next-app@latest but the build fails about 10 seconds in and I get this error:

```
npm ERR! Windows_NT 10.0.19045
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\Alex\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "--save-exact" "--save" "react" "react-dom" "next" "typescript" "@types/react" "@types/node" "@types/react-dom" "tailwindcss" "postcss" "autoprefixer" "eslint" "eslint-config-next"
npm ERR! node v18.16.0
npm ERR! npm  v2.15.12
npm ERR! path C:\Users\Alex\Desktop\anim8\node_modules\@types\react-dom\package.json
npm ERR! code ENOTDIR
npm ERR! errno -4058
npm ERR! syscall open

npm ERR! ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\Alex\Desktop\anim8\node_modules\@types\react-dom\package.json'
npm ERR!
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at:
npm ERR!     <https://github.com/npm/npm/issues>

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Alex\Desktop\anim8\npm-debug.log
```

My npm and node is updated to latest so I'm not sure what's going on here

Comment: This could be an error caused by your antivirus software removing / quarantining files. If you're sure this is not it, maybe check out [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56231358/8003058).

Comment: I disabled my antivirus, still not working. Now it's not even starting the initialization and now I'm getting the following: This version of C:\Users\Alex\Desktop\node_modules\node\bin\node.exe is not compatible with the version of Windows you're running. Check your computer's system information and then contact the software publisher. I've uninstalled and reinstalled node about 10 times now, no idea what's going on

Comment: Is it possible that you have installed a 32bit version while your computer is running 64bit or vice versa?

Comment: Double checking the versions now

Comment: Update: still getting the above error. I've uninstalled and reinstalled node multiple times ensuring the correct version, npm and node are updated. I'm running the command: npx create-next-app@latest and the installation is aborted due to the same error above. It keeps stopping because of this directory: C:\Users\Alex\Desktop\anim8\node_modules\@types\react-dom\package.json which doesn't exist until the installation begins so I'm not sure it's an issue on my end.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was due to permissions on my computer. For some reason, my OS was blocking operations and the fix is to run your cmd as admin and then run npx create-next-app@latest

I'm not sure if this is the best fix, but it works now.

In addition, you will also have to give permissions on the app itself.

Folder -> Properties -> Security -> Users -> Edit -> Full control